# How to localize a bot in C#

Tags: c#, localization, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need to build a **Chatbot** with Microsoft's bot builder, **in English and Spanish**.

It needs to be in the **C#** version.

I want to create **2 LUIS models**, one for english and one for spanish.

How can I use them in C#? For example, in NodeJs version, I'll just define the Luis models depending on the user's locale like this:

```
const recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer({ es: process.env.MICROSOFT_LUIS_MODEL_ES, en: process.env.MICROSOFT_LUIS_MODEL_EN })
```

but I couldn't find a way to do that same thing in C#. How can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can call 2 different LuisDialog given the message locale